# How can I properly connect my website IP address to my purchased domain using Cloudflare?

Tags: dns, cloudflare, godaddy-api

I purchased a domain using GoDaddy. I configured the nameservers, everything went fine. The domain is active on Cloudflare. But when i type the domain on browser it shows the welcome to nginx page. But when I type the domain IP address on the browser it shows my website. I configured the A and CNAME records as well.

[cloudflare records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9gJV.jpg)

[Domain website here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deCLN.jpg)

[IP address website here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJxXg.jpg)

I tried adding the domain name as the server_name [the django.conf configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfxuE.jpg)

[Bad gateway 502 error cloudflare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXncd.jpg)
I tried this new Nginx configuration
[New Nginx configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9Wn5.jpg)

but it shows me Bad request 400. My IP address is still working when typed in the browser. It's just the domain name that isn't working.

[Bad request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL0UU.jpg)

Comment: Show us your nginx configuration.

Comment: server{

 listen 80;
 server_name 13.50.16.100;

 
 location / {

  include proxy_params;
  proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ubuntu/passi/app.sock;

 }

Comment: Well, there you go. You've told it only to respond to a server_name of `13.50.16.100`. Add your domain name there.

Comment: The funniest thing is after I sent the nginx file I started thinking of that. Thanks. I'll try it now.

Comment: I tried it didn't work. I'll post a picture of it on the main post how I added the domain name.

Comment: You should only put your domain name in the "server_name", not the URL (remove the https://. 

The line should look like this: "server_name passifondation.com www.passifondation.com"

Comment: I tried it. Now I'm getting bad gateway. I'll pin the screenshot on the main post so you can see.

Comment: @SulaimanIbrahim Chances are CloudFlare is coming in via DNS. You may need **both** IP and domain in the list, or you might consider `listen 80 default_server` to make it fall-back to this record.

Comment: How can I add both the IP and the domain name? I tried adding the default_server but it's showing error syntax.

Comment: I tried a new Nginx configuration I found. Basically same problem. My IP address works but the domain name shows bad request. I posted the new Nginx configuration.